# Apache Java FTPclient order by timestamp

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftp-client

Is it possible to use Apache ftp client and list directory contents by timestamp?
I'm doing:

```
mFtpClient.listNames("-t .");
```

But returns an empty list.

Edit: I'm working with Filezilla Server.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved in this way:

```
public class CustomFTPClient extends FTPClient{

    public String[] listNamesOrdered(String pathname) throws IOException
    {
        if(pathname == null) pathname = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pathname.length() + 3);
        sb.append("-t -A1 ");
        sb.append(pathname);
        pathname = sb.toString();

        Socket socket = _openDataConnection_(FTPCmd.LIST, getListArguments(pathname));

        if (socket == null) {
            return null;
        }

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), getControlEncoding()));

        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            results.add(line);
        }

        reader.close();
        socket.close();

        if (completePendingCommand())
        {
            String[] names = new String[ results.size() ];
            return results.toArray(names);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I've copied the listNames method, and used the LIST command with -t parameter.